# How to list permissions of flatpak applications?

Tags: flatpak

When you install a flatpak via command line you get this:

```
 $ flatpak install flathub ind.ie.Gnomit 
Remote ‘flathub’ found in multiple installations:
1) system
2) user
Which do you want to use (0 to abort)? [0-2]: 2
Installing in user:
ind.ie.Gnomit/x86_64/stable        flathub ae8df0030467
  permissions: ipc, network, wayland, x11
  file access: host, xdg-run/dconf, ~/.config/dconf:ro
  dbus access: ca.desrt.dconf
ind.ie.Gnomit.Locale/x86_64/stable flathub 38f3aacb783a
Is this ok [y/n]:
```

It lists all permissions and things like that in a detailed way, which is quite nice.
However, how can I see this list later on?

I've tried `flatpak permission-show <…>`, but this does not show anything. `flatpak info` also only shows general stats.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's `flatpak info --show-permissions ind.ie.Gnomit`.

Also, `flatpak permission-show ind.ie.Gnomit` lists dynamic permissions that aren't included in `flatpak info`.

Comment: Agreed. The difference between those three commands is confusing.

Comment: well, `flatpak permissions com.valvesoftware.Steam` showed nothing/zilch/nill. Flatseal shows the permissions though.

Comment: Using `flatpak info --show-permissions <flatpak id>` did the trick.

Comment: @FilBot3 `flatpak permissions` takes a table name and object ID. `flatpak info` takes an app ID, as does `flatpak permission-show`.